# Can I just run the filewatching portion of ember serve?

Tags: ember-cli

My Ember app is embedded and served out of another project. I don't need livereload or an HTTTP server, but I would like to have my files recompiled by `ember-cli`. How do I make that happen?

Comment: `ember build --watch`

Comment: @steveax Ah I missed that. If you put it in an answer I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `--watch` flag with the build command.

```
ember build --watch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sane npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sane) to watch your app directory and rebuild on changes:

```
var sane = require('sane'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var watcher = sane(process.cwd()+'/app', {glob: ['**/*.js']});

function rebuild(filepath) {
    console.log(filepath+' changed, rebuilding');
    spawn('ember', ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
}
watcher.on('ready', function() { 
    console.log('watching '+process.cwd()+'/app');
});
watcher.on('change', function(filepath, root, stat) { 
    rebuild();
});
watcher.on('add', function(filepath, root, stat) { 
    rebuild();
});
watcher.on('delete', function(filepath, root, stat) { 
    rebuild();
});
```